# How to Print A Rectangle of Asterisks

Tags: jquery, html

How do I print a rectangle of asterisks using jQuery? I have two input fields which are used for taking input values two draw a rectangle of asterisks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new").click(function() {
    var firstnum = document.getElementById("column").value;
    var secondnum = document.getElementById("rows").value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">To Print Asterisks</h1>
<label>Enter Column</label>
<input type="text" id="column" placeholder="Enter The Column Number"><br>
<label>Enter Rows</label>
<input type="text" id="rows" placeholder="Enter The Rows Value"><br>
<button id="new">Submit</button>
```

The button is use to multiply the two values which we're given in the input fields and then create the rows and columns of the rectangle. The output should be below the submit button but I have no solution for them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is the problem? Surely there are lots of examples on the internet to find. Did you try any?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#new").click(function() {
            var firstnum = document.getElementById("column").value;
            var secondnum = document.getElementById("rows").value;
            var row = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < firstnum; i++) {
                row += "*";
            }
            row += "<br/>"; // Or "\n" if you want non-html markup result
            var rectangle = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < secondnum; i++) {
                rectangle += row;
            }
            $("#output").html(rectangle);
        });
    });
</script>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">To Print Asterisks</h1>
<label>Enter Column</label>
<input type="text" id="column" placeholder="Enter The Column Number"><br>
<label>Enter Rows</label>
<input type="text" id="rows" placeholder="Enter The Rows Value"><br>
<button id="new">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for Your Help